# any lldb debug information in console

Tags: xcode, ios7

I don't know why, but today, the crashing information is not showing in debug console. Only I can see SIGABRT but any information about that crash. When crashing, only "lldb" appear in console but no more information.

I check the run scheme is debug. Others nslog information that I put in my project display well, but I haven't any information about lldb debug.

I force crash i.e. with this code:

`NSMutableArray *lstTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *data = [lstTest objectAtIndex:0];`

This issue I have with all of my project for this reason I think that some properties of xCode I change and now I don't know what is it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next day the problem disappeared and returned to work fine xCode, including the debugger...